# Static field injection in Spring Unit test

Tags: spring, junit

I am using JUnit4 in my application where I tried to test a `UserService`, the current test case is simple:

```
Create a user named 'admin' and save it to the database.

The other test case will rely on this user.
```

So I use the `BeforeClass` to insert the record, however I have to use the `UserService` to save the user, but spring does  not support to inject static fields.

When I tried to create the `UserService` manually, I found that I have to fill the dependencies myself, I wonder if there is an alternative? Or there is something wrong with how I use JUnit?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/application-config.xml"})
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //@Autowired  // sprint does not suport this
    private static UserService us;
    private static User u;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        us = new UserServiceImpl(); // this UserService instance can not be used, since I have to fill the dependencies manually

        us.clear();
        u = new User();
        u.setUsername("admin");
        u.setPassword("pass");
        us.save(u);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after() {
        userService.delete(u.getId());
    }


    @Test
    public void testQuery() {
        List<User> list = userService.find();
        assertEquals(1, list.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangePassword() {
        userService.changePassword(u.getId(), u.getPassword(), "newpass");
        assertEquals("newpass", userService.findOne(u.getId()).getPassword());


        exception.expect(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        userService.changePassword("1", "32", "ss");

        exception.expect(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        userService.changePassword(u.getId(), "32", "ss");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `@Before`, and insert the user before each test.

Comment: If use `@Before` I have to use `@After` to clear the records. While I want to see the data in the database after the test.

Comment: Why would you **have** to use After. Don't, and leave the user in the database. What's the problem?

Comment: Use `@Before` which means it will insert a new user to the database, which means I do not know exactly the number of the total records in the database, then how can I make the assert: `assertEquals(1, list.size());`

Comment: Clear the database and insert a new user in `@Before`. As I explain here: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html#dont-cleanup-prepare